Umbraco 10 - "No physical template file was found" error intermittently on production
Umbraco 10 - "No physical template file was found" error intermittently on production
I'm encountering an issue with my Umbraco 10 site in production where I get a "Page Not Found" error intermittently.
Here’s what’s happening:

When I click on the "mypage" menu and then navigate to the "news" page, it works fine.
However, if I repeat the same process 2–3 times, I start getting a "Page Not Found" error.

Steps I’ve taken to resolve this issue:

I have republished the content, cleared the cache, and temp files multiple times.
Resaved the template files in Umbraco.
I verified that the correct template (NewsListPageAuthenticated.cshtml) is assigned to the newsListPage document type in Umbraco Backoffice.

enter image description here
**Error Details from Logs:
**
{
"@t":"2024-09-25T14:21:31.9707848Z",
"@mt":"No physical template file was found for document type with alias {Alias}",
"@l":"Warning",
"Alias":"newsListPage",
"SourceContext":"Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers.RenderController",
"ActionId":"bd9ab5e4-be30-44c7-8c90-54e052911c6f",
"ActionName":"Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers.RenderController.Index (Umbraco.Web.Common)",
"RequestId":"400008ec-0000-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb",
"RequestPath":"/my-page/news/",
"ProcessId":2244,
"ProcessName":"w3wp",
"ThreadId":56,
"Log4NetLevel":"WARN ",
"HttpSessionId":"82127ba1-0f8d-474c-7e56-6de08b65de26"
}


**
What I've Checked:**
1.The template NewsListPageAuthenticated.cshtml exists in the /Views folder on the production server.
2.Permissions on the Views folder seem correct.
3.The issue only occurs in production; it works fine in the local environment.
4.Tried different browsers (Chrome and Edge), but the issue persists.
5.We have cleared temp files.
6.We have cleared cache from BO.

Seems like a caching issue. Try to refresh, reload, rebuild and collect from settings -> published status. And a save and publish to both document type and content type.
